# No module named models

Tags: django

I know this error has been referred number of items in the forum, I tried it all but still it fails..

Case1:
from models import Category,Product

Error:
Could not import ecomstore.catalog.views. Error was: No module named models

Case2:
from ecomstore.catalog.models import Category,Product

Error:
could not import ecomstore.catalog.views. Error was: No module named models

Case3:
from catalog.models import Category,Product

Error:
could not import ecomstore.catalog.views. Error was: No module named models

Folder structure:
Catalog
        models.py
        views.py
        urls.py

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model): 
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True,
          help_text='Unique value for product page URL, created from name.') 
     description = models.TextField() 
     is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True) 
     meta_keywords = models.CharField("Meta Keywords",max_length=255,
          help_text='Comma-delimited set of SEO keywords for meta tag') 
     meta_description = models.CharField("Meta Description", max_length=255,   
          help_text='Content for description meta tag') 
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
     updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 

     class Meta: 
          db_table = 'categories' 
          ordering = ['-created_at'] 
          verbose_name_plural = 'Categories' 

     def __unicode__(self): 
          return self.name 

     @models.permalink 
     def get_absolute_url(self): 
          return ('catalog_category', (), { 'category_slug': self.slug })


class Product(models.Model): 
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True) 
     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, 
          help_text='Unique value for product page URL, created from name.') 
     brand = models.CharField(max_length=50)  
     sku = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
     price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)  
     old_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2,   
          blank=True,default=0.00) 
     image = models.CharField(max_length=50)           
     is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True) 
     is_bestseller = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
     is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
     quantity = models.IntegerField() 
     description = models.TextField() 
     meta_keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255,   
          help_text='Comma-delimited set of SEO keywords for meta tag') 
     meta_description = models.CharField(max_length=255,   
          help_text='Content for description meta tag') 
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
     updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 
     categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category) 

     class Meta: 
          db_table = 'products' 
          ordering = ['-created_at'] 

     def __unicode__(self): 
          return self.name 

     @models.permalink 
     def get_absolute_url(self): 
          return ('catalog_product', (), { 'product_slug': self.slug }) 

     def sale_price(self): 
          if self.old_price > self.price: 
               return self.price 
          else: 
               return None
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from models import Category,Product
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core import urlresolvers
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from forms import ProductAddToCartForm
from cart import cart

# Create your views here.
print 'prem in catalog views.py'

def index(request,template_name="catalog/index.html"):
     page_title = 'Musical instruments and Sheet Music for Musicians'
     return render_to_response(template_name,locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def show_category(request,category_slug,template_name="catalog/category.html"):
     c = get_object_or_404(Category,slug=category_slug)
     products = c.product_set.all()
     page_title = c.name
     meta_keywords = c.meta_keywords
     meta_description = c.meta_description
     return render_to_response(template_name,locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def show_product(request, product_slug, template_name="catalog/product.html"): 
     p = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=product_slug) 
     categories = p.categories.all() 
     page_title = p.name 
     meta_keywords = p.meta_keywords 
     meta_description = p.meta_description 
     # need to evaluate the HTTP method 
     if request.method == 'POST':
          # add to cart create the bound form 
          postdata = request.POST.copy() 
          form = ProductAddToCartForm(request, postdata) 
          #check if posted data is valid 
          if form.is_valid(): 
               #add to cart and redirect to cart page   
               cart.add_to_cart(request) 
               # if test cookie worked, get rid of it 
               if request.session.test_cookie_worked(): 
                    request.session.delete_test_cookie() 
               url = urlresolvers.reverse('show_cart') 
               return HttpResponseRedirect(url) 
     else: 
          # its a GET, create the unbound form.Note request as a kwarg 
          form = ProductAddToCartForm(request=request, label_suffix=':') 
     # assign the hidden input the product slug 
     form.fields['product_slug'].widget.attrs['value'] = product_slug 
     # set the test cookie on our first GET request 
     request.session.set_test_cookie() 
     return render_to_response(template_name, locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 





ecomstore
          catalog
                 models
                 urls
                 views
          cart
                 models
                 urls
                 views
                 cart
```

settings
   urls

Comment: try `from .models import .. ` if it is in the same app.

Comment: Check for circular imports

Comment: What's your folder structure like?

Comment: I have given the folder structure